# Magento custom module with two tables in the backend menu

Tags: php, xml, magento, custom-component

I spent 3 days trying to solve a problem with my custom module. I have a custom menu with 3 submenus

The first item (Regions), gets the correct table from the config.xml file but, when i'm trying to add another table for the second item (Subregions), I can't see anything,  I see a blank page. There is my  from the config.xml

```
    <models>
        <web>
            <class>Company_Web_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>web_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </web>
        <web_mysql4>
            <class>Company_Web_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <web>
                    <table>regions</table>
                </web>
                <subregions>
                    <table>subregions</table>
                </subregions>
            </entities>
        </web_mysql4>
  </models>
```

I've tried a lot of different possibilities.

Comment: Have you seen the description given by Alan Storm: [Magento Models and ORM Basics](http://alanstorm.com/magento_models_orm)? And what is your concrete question? When you tried many different possibilities, please share which ones and what was the outcome for each of them. Also it's not clear from your question which guideline you did follow and why you expect it to work. And what I forget all the time: Have you cleared the cache?

Comment: I would check into models of subregions and if they have correct init functions there.

Comment: Into Model directory, I have two files(Subregions.php and Web.php) and a Mysql4 folder.  Inside Subregions.php construct, in the class Company_Web_Model_Subregions I have  $this->_init('web/subregions'); Inside Mysql4 i have a Subregions folder (with the collection.php file) and a subregions.php with the class Company_Web_Model_Mysql4_Subregions and $this->_init('web/subregions', 'id'); on the construct.